# How to run a .jar java on MAC OS X?

Tags: java, macos, file

I would like to start a .jar from another java application on Mac.

But when launching the .jar , he told me that the file is not found , so that when I test the way he gives me , there is indeed the file.

Here is the code I use

```
String cmd = "/bin/bash java -jar " + System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/application support/MineServ2/mineserv2.jar";     
Process p = runtime.exec(cmd);
```

My question is how to run a .jar from another java application on a Mac

Comment: The problem is that you are not quoting a path containing spaces. It should be `String cmd = "/bin/bash java -jar \"" + System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/application support/MineServ2/mineserv2.jar\"";`

Comment: Or just use a ProcessBuilder and separate the command and parameters into an array or List

Comment: Also, don't forget to read the output/error stream

Comment: Sorry , but it did not change anything.

Comment: There should be gazillions of examples how to do this correctly, use the _search_

Comment: with \" in path, tha spaces are still not recognized

Comment: If possible please output the String "cmd" to make sure it's properly built.

Comment: miguels, I use ProcessBuilder now.

Answer (score 0):

with \" in path and I use aProcessBuilder, the spaces are still not recognized.

```js
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "\"" + System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/application support/MineServ2/mineserv2.jar\"");
Process p = pb.start();
```

Terminal message:

Last login: Sat Dec 26 22:50:12 on ttys000
MacBook-Air-de-OXYTOMIRE:~ oxytomire$ /Volumes/EMTEC/lancer.command ; exit;
Error: Unable to access jarfile "Users/oxytomire/Library/application
logout

Why ?